# Can we execute az PowerShell module commands inside of a runspace in a .net console app deployed as a webjob on Azure app service?

Tags: .net, azure, powershell, azure-appservice, runspace

I've a webjob running in an azure app service that uses runspace to execute azure powershell module commands. Locally it's working fine because I can install az module directly using Windows powershell but when I deploy it to Azure, it fails.

Initially I was getting following error when I was executing  `Connect-AzAccount -Identity`

```
Connect-AzAccount : The term 'Connect-AzAccount' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet
```

Then I tried to install az module inside of a runspace and I started getting another error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

Here is how I'm trying to install az module:

```
    runSpace.Open();

    RunspaceInvoke scriptInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke();
    scriptInvoker.Invoke("Install-PackageProvider Nuget -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force -Scope CurrentUser");
    scriptInvoker.Invoke("Import-PackageProvider Nuget");
    scriptInvoker.Invoke("Install-Module Az.Websites -Force -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser");
    scriptInvoker.Invoke("Import-Module Az.Websites");
    scriptInvoker.Invoke("Install-Module Az.Storage -Force -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser");
    scriptInvoker.Invoke("Import-Module Az.Storage");
```

So is it possible to execute az powershell module command in appservice?

Comment: Could you please try with only `Connect-azaccount `  does the same error appearing..!!

Answer (score 0):

- There are multiple ways to address the issue, below are the few resolutions.

**Fix 1:**
To resolve the issue run the below command.

```
Import-Module Az.Accounts
```

When you executed the above command, it will prompt you for the credentials.

**Fix 2:**

- Install the **Module Az.**
  By using the below PowerShell cmdlet,

```
Import-Module Az
```

- Connect to the **AzAccount** like below,

```
Connect-AzAccount
```

- You can check the worked [solution](https://azurelessons.com/the-term-connect-azaccount-is-not-recognized/) from here.
- Also check this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64200680/18935775) with the related discussions.